# Single word for "women lover"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

Is there a single word for "women lover"?

Comment: I'm surprised this has not been asked on ELU already?

Comment: What do you mean by "women lover"? Someone who appreciates women? Someone who is sexually attracted to women? Someone who engages in sexual intercourse with women? "Lover" is a vague and ambiguous term.

Comment: @suməlic I read the title and immediately thought _mistress_, i.e., female lover (rather than lover of females).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Yeah, I was wondering about mentioning that too, but I guess it would have to be "woman lover" (or for the plural, "women lovers") in that case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about *philogynist*?

> [**philogynist**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Philogynist): a lover or friend of women.

Comment: Or the other way around, if you put the *gyne-* first.

Comment: @tchrust. I thought about that one. But it was a bit too close to Barmar's answer.

Answer (score 5):

It's not a common word, but *gynophile* appears to fit.

Comment: Yours is also spelled *gynephile*.  Sometimes you will also  find those who are attracted to women referred *gynesexuals*.  Which of the two terms is to be preferred, or even used, or why, I leave to the [social politicians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Androphilia_and_gynephilia).

Comment: Awesome Venn diagram of such terms: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Androphilia_and_gynephilia

Answer (score 3):

**Philogynist** (n. A lover or friend of women; one who esteems woman as the higher type of humanity; -- opposed to misogynist.) is the first result on the [Writers' Reverse Dictionary](http://www.writersdictionary.com/).

> Words that mean "women lover" are philogynist, agapet, mistress, don juan, lawrence, baby, cap, cicisbeo, electra, eros, gallant, gigolo, lady, philander, and philanderer. - **[Words that mean "women lover" - Writers' Reverse Dictionary](http://www.writersdictionary.com/search/women+lover?var=sp%3D%2A)**

Comment: You might want to look before you leap. **Philogynist** was given as an answer over two years ago. We prefer not to get duplicate answers; the fact that you provided a *slightly* longer definition doesn't really make this a worthy answer. And look at what you copied: mistress, baby, eros and lady don't fit the question. "Don Juan" *might* be a good answer (or maybe not; I haven't researched it); if you believe that it is, you might want to [edit] your question to focus on that.

Comment: The main purpose of this answer is to provide substantiation and a means to help others help themselves with the tool provided. The tool's results page usually has a few good results at the beginning and the rest is gibberish. If you suggest that I should take the gibberish out I could, but it may be helpful to others who aren't looking for one specific word.

Comment: @Scott: The question is so vague and cryptic that John's list is probably actually useful. It's hard to tell what would or wouldn't fit. It adds a lot of stuff that's not in Elian's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Rarely used these days... Lothario.

> [Lothario](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lothario):  a man whose chief interest is seducing women

Answer (score 0):

A *red-blooded male* is a common colloquialism.

Comment: Could you have a red-blooded sapphist?

Answer (score -1):

I'm thinking of a word that would be alliterative of "genius" and also indicate an extreme infatuation with women. So, I thought of linking two  words "gyne" and "maniac" and came up with a "gynemaniac," but I don't find it anywhere as a word.

Answer (score -3):

"Straight"(slang) a man is called this way if his only desire are women, and a man has free will to love as much women as he can.

Comment: _Straight_ does not work if we're talking about a female woman-lover. Also, no matter how macho one might be, _women_ is a plural (not a non-count collective) in English, and you must therefore say _as many women_, not _*as much women_.